# How to include external file as Sphinx documentation similar to a code block?

Tags: python-sphinx, code-documentation

How to include external file as Sphinx documentation similar to a code block?

And how can I make it style the syntax color?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it here: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude

```
.. literalinclude :: <path/to/file>
   :language: <file_language>
```

Comment: Thanks! That link seems to be outdated. Up-to-date link to the directive: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude